# Wiremock JSON template: basicAuth and doesNotMatch not working

Tags: wiremock

I have the following JSON response template for use with Wiremock.
The idea is, that status 401 is returned, if `username != "username"`:

```json
{
   "request":{
      "method":"GET",
      "url":"/basicAuth",
      "basicAuth":{
         "username":{
            "doesNotMatch":"^username$"
         },
         "password":"password"
      }
   },
   "response":{
      "status":401
   }
}
```

When running a test that is supposed to use that template, I get the following error (path shortened):
`com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.standalone.MappingFileException: Error loading file C:\.....\basicAuth_get_status_401.json:`

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic auth matcher will only do an exact equality check on the username and password - it's not possible to use matchers at this point.

Another option you might consider is to implementing a `StubRequestFilter` extension that implements the rules you require.

There's an example of this here: https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock/blob/master/src/test/java/com/github/tomakehurst/wiremock/RequestFilterAcceptanceTest.java#L187